# Can't filter in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: geocoding, arcgis-online

I have two layers in AGOL: a county boundary layer for Nevada I got from census.gov and geocoded points (which I dragged and dropped a CSV with addresses into AGOL).

Going to each layer's options, there is no option to filter. Upon doing a search on the issue I came across this:

"You can create filters on hosted feature layers, ArcGIS Server feature service layers, and ArcGIS Server map service layers that have associated attribute data; you cannot create filters on map notes or features imported from a file."

source: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/apply-filters.htm

Anyone know a way around this? I'm new to GIS in general.

Answer (score 1):

Your layers must be a [hosted web feature service](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/09/22/how-to-create-a-hosted-feature-service/) to filter your data.
It's my understanding that if you are not a member of an [ArcGIS Online organization](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/create-account.htm) (i.e., you have an ArcGIS online [public account](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/create-account.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_D91DD2A709AE4FB68A9CC095F1688E05) such as those used with a home version of ArcMap) then you won't be able to manage a web feature service.

A workaround would be to sign up for a free [ArcGIS Developer Plan](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/plans/) to create web feature services. I was having the same issue and tried it today. Once you create your "Organization" you can add new items (including csv files) and create a hosted layer. Once that happens, you'll be able to use the filter capabilities on your new layer and create web applications with filtering drop-downs.

Just be aware of your "credit" limit when performing geoprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this 2 layers to your map. (Preferably save them to same geodatabase) Organise symbology, colors, map properties. Share this map as service.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the map was set up, the author may not have enabled filtering. In this case, nothing can be done.  I assume that since you dragged and dropped the .csv in, that is what you were attempting to filter on, and have the ability to workaround using Codesurfer's answer, but for others who may be searching this question and don't own the data, I wanted to throw this out there.

From [documentation on applying filters for ArcGIS Online:](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/apply-filters.htm)

> As a map author, you can also set up interactive filters that help
>   your audience explore data themselves. By providing prompts and hints
>   about the available values in the layer, you can guide your audience
>   toward other filters they might want to apply on the features.